# QEMU with SunOS 4 - how to transfer files

Tags: qemu, sunos

How do I transfer files between the host and the guest when using SunOS 4 under QEMU?
I have followed this guide:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/SunOS_4.1.4
But when I try to rlogin or rcp, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo rlogin -l root localhost  
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

$ sudo rcp test.txt localhost:  
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused lost connection
```

QEMU version: 2.10, SunOS version: 4.1.4, Ubuntu version (host): 16.04

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you try to run rlogin/rcp through sudo?

Comment: Why don't you use NFS ? Create a virtual net between the host and the dom and run nfs vers 3 over that. It is possible to configure the host firewall such that rpcbind  is protected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rlogin` and `rcp` are considered to be somewhat obsolete nowadays and have been replaced by `ssh` and `scp` respectively, the first "s" standing fore "secure". The reason I am telling you this is that both `ssh` and `scp` connect to the `sshd` server via port 22. Coincidence? I think not. Your host system does not have a true `rcp` or `rlogin` and has instead aliased both commands to the `ssh` equivalent.

The reason it is like this is because `ssh` long ago replaced these two commands as the preferred method for remote log in and file transfer but somebody at Ubuntu decided that it would be better to alias `rlogin` and `rcp` instead of doing the right thing (which is just leave them uninstalled, so you know they are properly missing).

Apparently, Ubuntu has an `rsh-client` package that installs the real utilities. I don't know exactly how to install a package on Ubuntu, but it's probably something like

```
sudo apt-get install rsh-client
```

Once you have got into your SunOs guest an can upload files to it, the first thing you should do is install an `ssh` server so you can use the `ssh` tools properly.

Comment: @RetroQuestion2017 Good news. Was my guess at the install command correct?

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Comment: ssh on SunOS 4 ....   i do have a machine which should be able to run sunos 4 but will sshd be anything but slow ... yes signing on will be slow and well current ssh depends on a rather large software stack which includes perl.  Don't expect to be able to build a current perl on sunos4 !